# sqlzoo: Matching name and capital

Tags: sql

I'm going through sqlzoo and I'm supposed to "Show the name and capital where the name and the capital have the same number of characters"

The code I came up with was the following.

select name, len(name),capital,len(capital) from world where len(capital) = len(name);

This produces the result that the task demanded, but it won't let me proceed?

Did I miss something here? Is there a better way to do this that sqlzoo wanted me to put in?